# Hamcrest matcher to compare superclass and subclass

Tags: java, junit, matcher, hamcrest

I have following classes:

```
abstract class Answer<T> {}
class AnswerInt extends Answer<Integer> {}
class AnswerText extends Answer<String> {}
```

Now I'd like to use Hamcrest Matcher in following test (it's just simplified example):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Answer a = new AnswerInt(5);
    assertThat(a, is(new AnswerInt(5))); // Compile error
}
```

but I get compile error: 
`The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type MatcherAssert is not applicable for the arguments (Answer, Matcher<AnswerInt>)`.

I do understand the error message but I don't get why `assertThat` is defined like .. `Matcher<? super T>`.

**Is it possible to write assertions that mix superclass and subclass?**

Next, I'd like to write assertions like:

```
Map<String,Answer> answerMap = questionary.getAnswerMap();
assertThat(answerMap, allOf(
    hasEntry("var1", new AnswerInt(5)),
    hasEntry("var2", new AnswerText("foo"))
));
```

But I'm getting the same error.

I'm using Hamcrest version 1.3

Comment: you can do it other way around: `assertThat(new AnswerInt(5), is(a));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run your test with Java 8 it compiles. For previous versions you have to give the compiler a hint:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Answer a = new AnswerInt(5);
    assertThat(a, Matchers.<Answer>is(new AnswerInt(5)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using equalTo(...)

`assertThat(a, equalTo(new AnswerInt(5)));`

What we try to do is downcast, so if you do:

`assertThat(new AnswerInt(5), is(a));`

Take a closer look at the message:

```
The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (Answer<Integer>, Matcher<AnswerInt>)
```

But you actually did something like:

```
assertThat(<? super T>, Matcher<T>) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the workaround (to switch expected and tested) parameters would work in the simple case, but I suspect that it's not the right way to do it: I'd have wrong test messages (switched expected and tested) and in the more complex case (e.g. usage of allOf) it couldn't be used at all.

Comment: True. But this is the issue, we tried to downcast. As a better solution, perhaps you should build your own matcher.